# How to change the path of conda base

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am a `Linux` cluster user. While I installed a version of `miniconda`, the cluster had its own version of `anaconda`. When I do

```
conda info --envs
```

the output is

```
# conda environments:
#
         /home/user/miniconda3/envs/my_envs
base  *  /usr/local/anaconda
```

This type of settings may sometimes result in the "permission denied" error. Is there a method to change the path of the base environment to `/home/user/miniconda3`?

Comment: Why don't you use the system installed anaconda and configure the `env_path` to `/home/user/miniconda3/envs/my_envs` for yourself in `~/.condarc`?

Comment: @Simba What I want is ```base  *  /home/user/miniconda3```

Answer (score 11):

1. Prepend `condabin/conda` into `PATH`. Write the following settings into your shell init files. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` for Bash, `~/.zshrc` for ZSH.

   ```sh
   export PATH="/home/user/miniconda3/condabin:$PATH"
   ```

   Reopen a new shell. Check the result of `which -a conda`. Make sure the `conda` from `/home/user/miniconda3/condabin` takes precedence over other `conda` executables.
2. Cleanup and redo `conda init`.

   Open your shell init files. Remove the following content,

   ```
   # >>> conda initialize >>>
   ...
   # <<< conda initialize <<<
   ```

   Save the configuration files.

   Reopen a **new** shell, type `/home/user/miniconda3/condabin/conda init` once.

   Done.

---

Update: But I still recommend you use the Anaconda already installed on your system. There's no need to install two `conda` packages.

Because `conda` is a python manger and a package manager. You can create environments with any version of Python you want with command `conda`.

The only difference between an Anaconda and a Miniconda installation is that, the "base" environment where `conda` is installed from Anaconda, is bundled with more pre-installed packages than the "base" env from Miniconda.

Configuring `conda` to store environments under your home directory is enough.

```sh
conda config --prepend pkgs_dirs /home/user/.conda/pkgs
conda config --prepend envs_dirs /home/user/.conda/envs
```

All you need is the execution permission of the command `conda`, the environments and pkg caches are stored under your home folder.

Comment: Hi @Simba, thanks for those constructional suggestions. The problem does not lie in ```anaconda``` itself; the problem lies in the "permission denied" error. Since I am not the cluster admin, I prefer my own version of ```miniconda``` to access full rights.

Answer (score 2):

When one installs different distributions of Anaconda, the package shell scripts change the base environment. (That was what happened when I installed Miniforge3 to experiment with python for M1 Silicon)

Try to See: echo $PATH and one can see paths to active base environment but those paths wont be on ~/.bash_profile PATH

To change default/base environment follow below steps:

On Mac:

1. Open your /Users/*your username*/**.zshrc** (in a TextEditor)
2. There would be the paths to current base environment. Replace the path with the   one which should be the default one for your case.
3. Close and Reopen Terminal.
4. Run 'conda info --envs' and the base env would be changed to path mentioned in ~/.zshrc