# Anaconda - Move .conda .continuum .condarc into another path

Tags: anaconda, conda

**I was wondering if someone knew how to change the 'automatic installation' by anaconda of those 3 files/folders.( .conda .continuum .condarc )**

[image of the three files/folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Dqm.png)

When I installed Anaconda and ran it for the first time. It automatically installed those three files into C:\Users\NAME.

I don't want that.

I want it to install them, f.ex., into C:\Anaconda

I've tried those answers :

- [How to change the path of conda base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131555/how-to-change-the-path-of-conda-base)
- [How to move .conda from one folder to another at the moment of creating the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67610133/how-to-move-conda-from-one-folder-to-another-at-the-moment-of-creating-the-envi)
- [Set a path for the ~/.conda/pkgs directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697342/set-a-path-for-the-conda-pkgs-directory)

Looked-up here :

- https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html

Without success.

So I think I gave google the wrong prompt because maybe I don't have the correct terms.

Does someone please has any ideas ?

Thanks for your time.